# Idiomatic handling of missing fields when deconstructing an Elixir map?

Tags: elixir

What is the best way to get a "default" value in Elixir, or to trap an error, in the case of a pattern matching error in a map deconstruction?

```
iex(1)> %{"a" => a} = %{"a" => 1, "b" => 2}
%{"a" => 1, "b" => 2}
iex(2)> a
1
iex(3)> %{"m" => m} = %{"a" => 1, "b" => 2}

** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: %{"a" => 1, "b" => 2}
```

Has to work cleanly in deeply nested cases too:

```
iex(4)> %{"b" => %{"c" => %{"e" => myvar}}} = %{"a" => 1, "b" => %{"c" => %{"d" => 4, "e" => 5}}}
%{"a" => 1, "b" => %{"c" => %{"d" => 4, "e" => 5}}}
iex(5)> myvar
5
iex(6)> %{"b" => %{"c" => %{"e" => myvar}}} = %{"a" => 1, "f" => 6}             

** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: %{"a" => 1, "f" => 6}
```

So in cases above I like `a` and `myvar` to fallback to a default, or else some kind of clean way to branch to a handler function. If possible, I'd prefer a solution which does not involve an error handler though.

Comment: In Elixir, there is no destructuring assignment syntax like in ES6 for example. Elixir's pattern matching may seem similar, but it's not the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the deleted comment to Aleksei's answer:

> yes I can write a function, but I'm looking for an *idiomatic* answer.

The idomatic thing to do in Elixir is to fail if the match fails, or to ensure that the match always succeeds.

Depending on the context there are multiple ways to provide "default" clauses that will always match. Here are 3 examples using `case`, `with`, and multiple function clauses.

Case:

```elixir
case value do
  %{"a" => a} -> a
  _ -> "default value"
end
```

With:

```elixir
with %{"a" => a} <- value do
  a
else
  _ -> "default value"
end
```

Function clauses:

```elixir
def default_function_clause(%{"a" => a}), do: a
def default_function_clause(_), do: "default value"
```

In all cases, providing a map with an `"a"` key will return the value, otherwise `"default value"`.

Comment: FWIW, I have restored the original version of the answer; I keep a right to answer what I want to share.

Comment: “to fail if the match fails”—the core of [tag:elixir] structure dig supply, `Access` behaviour, strongly disagrees with this statement :)

Answer (score 1):

I'll let others with more experience weigh in on what's more idiomatic, but I will often provide optional defaults via a module attribute and then allow overrides via a merge function.  Something like this (using [Map.merge/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#merge/2) or [Keyword.merge/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Keyword.html#merge/2) for keyword lists):

```
defmodule Something do

  @defaults %{"a" => "alpha", "b" => "beta"}

  def foo(input) do
    input_or_defaults = Map.merge(@defaults, input)
    # ... 
  end
end
```

If your question is really delving into error trapping, then here's an example of an "implicit rescue" that would handle the case when there is no match:

```
def risky_stuff(input) do
   do_match(input)
rescue e in UndefinedFunctionError ->
  {:error, "Unable to match"}
end

defp do_match(%{"a" => a}), do: "something with a"
defp do_match(%{"b" => b}), do: "something with b"
```

Have a look at the ["implicit try"](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#def/2-rescue-catch-after-else) for some explanation of this.

However, I think you'll find the functionality you need with a merge.

Comment: yes I"d prefer something that doesn't require trapping an error. I'll make that clearer in the question. However the merge option is decent if there's nothing else. I suspect Kernel.get_in may have some smart way of doing it that I haven't figured out yet. https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#get_in/2

Comment: @Everett `Map.merge/2` is shallow, `Map.merge(%{a: %{b: %{c: 42}}}, %{a: :boom!}) #⇒ %{a: :boom!}`, but technically one might use [`Access.key/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html#key/2) like `get_in(%{"a" => 1}, [Access.key("b", %{}), Access.key("c", %{}), Access.key("d", :default)]) #⇒ :default` but I doubt anyone would call it “idiomatic.” :)

Answer (score 0):

It obviously cannot be done with match because there is literally impossible to fit the default with the match syntax.

If you know that the map has no `nil` values you might do somewhat like [`get_in/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#get_in/2), and then use default if the outcome is `nil`.

Also, it’s not as complicated to produce a function yourself.

```rb
safe_get_in = fn keys, input, default ->
  Enum.reduce_while(keys, input, fn key, acc ->
    case acc do
      %{^key => level_down} -> {:cont, level_down}
      _ -> {:halt, default}
    end
  end)
end

safe_get_in.(~w|a b c d|, %{"a" => 1, "f" => 6}, 42)
#⇒ 42
safe_get_in.(~w|b c d|, %{
  "a" => 1, "b" => %{"c" => %{"d" => 4, "e" => 5}}}, 42)
#⇒ 4
```

This is not very common to get to deeply nested value without knowing whether it’s there or not, that’s why there is no implementation for the case in the standard library.

Comment: No chance I’ll let this answer to be changed.

Comment: Unfortunately it is indeed very common, when parsing API JSON data into maps, to have missing nested data.

Comment: I never said it’s uncommon in web development. I said it’s uncommon in [tag:elixir] itself, and the question is tagged [tag:elixir] only. Even in web development, if this nested data is significant, one wants to fail, and one should not bother otherwise. The answer by @adam-millerchip covers this use-case pretty fine.

Comment: And why do you again make assumptions, in this case that JSON data must be "web development"? JSON is an extremely common tree data format in data science generally, obviously, which has nothing to do with web development. As per the "Elixir" tag so what you're saying is I must tag the question with every possible domain where missing data in a tree structure is possible? That's absurd. Sorry.